# Intended constant variables that need to be initialized at runtime

Tags: c

I have a variable that I want to initialize at runtime before the rest of the program runs. After initialization, I don't want the value of the variable to change. Is there any C language construct to go about doing this ?

Let my main C program is contained in a file Prog.c

```
//Contents of Prog.c
//...includes.. and variable initialization

int main(..)
{
    //Initialize variables here
    //.. Huge program after this where I don't want these constants to change
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it indirectly through `const` pointers, at least:

```
typedef struct  {
  int answer;
} state;

const state * state_init(void)
{
  static state st;

  st.answer = 42;  /* Pretend this has to be done at run-time. */

  return &st;
}

int main(void)
{
  const state *st = state_init();
  printf("the answer is %d, and it's constant\n"," st->answer);
}
```

This way, all `main()` has is a `const` pointer to some `state` which it cannot modify.

Answer (score 2):

A constant global should work, yes?

```
const int val = 3; // Set before main starts
                   // const, so it will never change.

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", val);  // using val in code
}
```

---

However, if the value isn't known at compile-time, you can set it at run-time this way:

```
const int const* g_pVal;

int main(void)
{
    static const int val = initialize_value();

    g_pVal = &val;

    printf("%d\n", *g_pVal);
}
```

Comment: What if the variable needs to be accessed from other functions in other files ?

Comment: `*g_pVal` is easily `extern`ed, and available in any linked files.  Its a **global**.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is if you read your value as a non constant and then call a function which take a constant value and pass your variable to it. Inside the function you make all the wished operations.